# Error from chokidar (D:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'D:\pagefile.sys'

Tags: vue.js, npm, webpack

I keep running into problem when I tried to run my Vue app today using the `npm run serve` command. I've done this countless time with the same repository but it gave this error when I started it just now.

```
This dependency was not found:

* node:console in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/views/News.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

To install it, you can run: npm install --save node:console
Error from chokidar (D:\): Error: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, lstat 'D:\pagefile.sys'
```

What I have tried to fix the problem:

- Updates all the packages using `npm install`
- Deleted the `node_modules` folder and reinstalled the entire dependency
- Reload the git repository to the point where it still worked previously
- Installed `node:console` using the command `npm install --save node:console` which returns the following error instead:

```
npm ERR! code EUNSUPPORTEDPROTOCOL
npm ERR! Unsupported URL Type "node:": node:console

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-06-03T16_45_28_752Z-debug.log
```

Obviously, none of the fixes had work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind my error. It seems in my careless mistake I've appended `import {timeEnd} from 'node:console'` to the `News.vue` file just prior to creating a commit

Answer (score 0):

execute command as admin
powercfg -h off